# bash command substitution on external script function receives incorrect exit status

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

This example was tested on Mac El Capitan with bash

main_script.sh:

> NOTE: func_a and func_b are identical except for the line that the local variable `output` is declared.

```
func_a () {
    local output
    output="$(./external.sh some_function)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "A zero result ($?) -> $output <- end"
    else
        echo "A other result ($?) -> $output <- end"
    fi
}

func_b () {
    local output="$(./external.sh some_function)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "B zero result ($?) -> $output <- end"
    else
        echo "B other result ($?) -> $output <- end"
    fi
}

func_a
func_b
```

external.sh:

```
some_function () {
    echo "this is the output"
    return 1
}

"$@"
```

When i run main_script the output is:

```
A other result (1) -> this is the output <- end
B zero result (0) -> this is the output <- end
```

For what reason would the declaration of a local variable on the same line as the command substitiution affect the results?  Could this be a bug or am i missing something?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Well aware of how to debug a bash script and what set -x does.  I simply tried to make the output as clear as possible.  I know what the problem is, now i wonder why.  Seems declaring a local var returns zero no matter what.. Seems like a bash bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that **`$?` in `func_b` reflects the success of the `local` builtin rather than the success of the command substitution (`$(...)`)**.

The **`local` builtin succeeds if the assignment is *syntactically correct*** -  *irrespective of whether any command substitution on the RHS fails* or not.

Note that this applies analogously to the `declare` and `export` builtins.

To illustrate with a simple example:

```
declare output="$(false)"; echo $? # -> 0(!) - even though `false` obviously fails.
```

By contrast, **if *no builtin is involved* - in the case of a *simple variable assignment* - a command substitution's failure *is* reflected in `$?`**:

```
output="$(false)"; echo $? # -> 1(!) - simple assignment; $(...) exit code is reported
```

---

This **counter-intuitive difference in behavior is explained by the fact that `local` / `declare` / `export` are *builtins* rather than part of the *shell syntax***.

As builtins (built-in commands), they are treated like *commands*, and commands are expected to signal their success/failure via their *own* exit code; in the case of said builtins, as stated, a syntactically correct assignment is considered success - in other words: if *something* could be assigned - even if that something is the null string due to a failing command substitution on the RHS - the builtin succeeded.

Comment: Thats what i figured was going on.  Kinda silly that declaring a variable would supersede the success of the assignment.  But then again things are rarely intuitive in shell script land..

Comment: @arctelix: It's definitely counter-intuitive; I've added some background information that hopefully explains at least why it happens.